# Lightning Report Chart on Case Detail - Filter by Account

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-report-type, report-chart

I am trying to get a Report Chart component in Lightning Service Console to auto-filter down to display average response time by account (Parent account for the case being viewed). However, the only option in the Filter By setting for the component is Case ID. I have already created a custom report type and added both Account Name and Account Id via lookup to the case layout, however, I still do not have the option to filter by them on the component.

Answer (score 1):

Report chart component allows filtering by the Id of the record page you are adding the chart to. If it is Case page, the report can only be filtered by Case Id, and that too provided the report type includes Case.

You can create a visualforce page with analytics:reportChart tag where you can add a filter. In the example below I am filtering by contact id linked to the case.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
<analytics:reportChart reportId="Id of report"
                   hideonerror="false"
                   filter="{column:'FK_CNTC_ID', operator:'equals', value:'{!Case.Contact.Id}'}" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="false"></analytics:reportChart>
```

You have to check the 'Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages' property of the VF page for the page to show in the Visualforce component inside Lightning App Builder.